# “405 method not allowed” for “DELETE” method

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I'm getting a '405 Method Not Allowed' when I attempt for a DELETE in my staging environment.

Is there something I should be looking out for?

When I run it on my local machine (IIS 10.0) it works fine and is able to delete an ID but when I run it on my staging environment it doesn't work and returns a 405 error on swagger.

This only seems to be occurring for all **delete endpoints**

This is how I've implemented delete endpoints:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("{Id}")]
```

current output from response header:

```
allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE 
content-length: 1293 
content-type: text/html 
date: Mon, 14 Sep 2020 04:15:15 GMT 
server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 
x-powered-by: ASP.NET 
x-powered-by-plesk: PleskWin
```

I've got the current setup for my startup.cs

```
private static void ConfigureCors(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("testAppPolicy", builder =>
  {
     builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .Build();
 }));
}
```

I know it's quite a vague question but any tips on where I could start looking on how to debug this situation?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and error message, I suggest you could firstly make sure you have installed the right asp.net core module for the staging server.

Then I suggest you could try to remove the WebDAVModule in the IIS server.

More details, you could try to modify the web.config as below format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebDAV" />
            <!-- I removed the following handlers too, but these
                 can probably be ignored for most installations -->
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
            <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        </handlers>

        <aspNetCore processPath="yourasp.net core config" 
                    stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                    stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't have a config file in my solution only a launchsettings.json

Comment: Because since it's .net core I'm using json files

Comment: If you host the application on IIS server, you will need web.config file. Do you host your application on IIS server?